# owlCarousel reverse slide movement direction on Prev and Next with animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

The default behavior of the owlCarousel works fine, clicking on Next slides to the right and clicking Prev sliding the slide to the left.

But after using animation both are always going to the same direction.

Here is a quick jsfiddle to show the issue:

[JSFiddle owl animation sample](https://jsfiddle.net/skra10fu/1/)

So in the fiddle, the slider should go up on Next and down on Prev, but its always going up. I tried all kind of animation options from Animate.css.

I also tried to do it using JQuery and owl carousel triggers to overwride the animation on clicking next or prev, did not work as well.

```
$(".news-slider .owl-nav .owl-next").click(function(e){

    var carousel = caseStudeisContent.data('owl.carousel');
    animateIn = "slideInLeft";
    animateOut = "slideOutRight";

    carousel.settings.animateOut = animateOut;
    carousel.settings.animateOut = animateOut;
    carousel.options.animateIn = animateIn;
    carousel.options.animateIn = animateIn;

    caseStudeisContent.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
    console.log("next");
    caseStudeisContent.trigger("next.owl.carousel");
});

$(".news-slider .owl-nav .owl-prev").click(function(e){

    var carousel = caseStudeisContent.data('owl.carousel');
    animateIn = "slideLeft";
    animateOut = "slideInRight";

    carousel.settings.animateOut = animateOut;
    carousel.settings.animateOut = animateOut;
    carousel.options.animateIn = animateIn;
    carousel.options.animateIn = animateIn;

    caseStudeisContent.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
    console.log("prev");
    caseStudeisContent.trigger("prev.owl.carousel");
})
```

[image: Here is sample illustration of how the slides should animate.]

Comment: your fiddle seems to work. Where is your issue?

Comment: Next moves the slide up m the previous should move it down, like a vertical spinner

Comment: @gaetanoM, I added an illustration on how the animation should be on clicking previous and next

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible to do it using Owl Carousel. Keep in mind this library has its limitations.
One way to fix it, in this case, would be use `transform` property.

First, remove `animateOut: 'fadeOutUp'` and `animateIn: 'fadeInUp'`. It will turn into a "normal" slider. Then, add transform property rotating `.owl-carousel` and `.owl-item`:

```css
owl-carousel {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(25px); // also move it a little bit
}
```

Comment: smart, in my situation, I will have to change a lot of things in the design to achieve it with this solution. thanks